# WORHP very slow on locally affine function

Tags: worhp

I have a problem where I need to minimize a locally affine function and I choose to use WORHP (later the locally affine property shall be replaced by other local conditions) . The value of the function as well as the derivative and the hessian (which is trivial) is provided as user input and is computed very fast. I have simple box constraints, i.e. all variables should be between 0 and 1 and no other constraints. I consider this as a rather easy problem. Still WORHP need to iterate over 350 times leading to a computation time which is rather high for the easy problem.
Is there a way to choose better parameters for this kind of situation?
The python code I use is given below (The input values are computed by another process.)

```
def worhp_minimize(n, f, df, hmf, xl, xu, init_x):#f:R^n -> R, df: R^n -> R^n, g:R^n -> R^m, gl in R^m, gu in R^m, dg in R^nxm, hmf:R^n -> R^k, hmg: R^(n+m) -> R^k
  def vectorize(attribute):
    return [float(attribute[i]) for i in range(0,len(attribute))]
  def assign(attribute,list):
    for i in range(0,len(list)):
      if list[i] == "inf":
        attribute[i] = par.infty
      elif list[i] == "-inf":
        attribute[i] = -par.infty
      else:
        if isinstance(list[i],int):
          attribute[i] = list[i]
        else:
          attribute[i] = float(list[i])
  def user_f(opt, wsp, par, cnt):
    opt.f = wsp.scale_obj * f(vectorize(opt.x))
  def user_df(opt, wsp, par, cnt):
    assign(wsp.df.val, wsp.scale_obj*df(vectorize(opt.x)))
  #def user_dg(opt, wsp, par, cnt):
  #  assign(wsp.dg.val, dg(vectorize(opt.x)))
  def user_hm(opt, wsp, par, cnt):
    hess = wsp.scale_obj * hmf(vectorize(opt.x))
    l = len(hess)
    index = 0
    for j in range(0,l):
      wsp.hm.val[l*(l-1)//2 + j] = hess[j][j]
      for i in range(j,l):
        wsp.hm.val[index] = hess[i][j]
        index +=1
  if worhp.check_version(worhp.MAJOR, worhp.MINOR, worhp.PATCH):
    exit(1)
  opt = worhp.OptVar()
  wsp = worhp.Workspace()
  par = worhp.Params()
  cnt = worhp.Control()
  worhp.pre_init(opt, wsp, par, cnt)
  worhp.init_params(par)
  par.NLPprint = 1
  status = worhp.read_params_no_init("worhp.xml", par)
  if status == worhp.DATA_ERROR or status == worhp.INIT_ERROR:
    exit(1)
  opt.n = n
  opt.m = 0
  worhp.init(opt, wsp, par, cnt)
  if cnt.status != worhp.FIRST_CALL:
    print("Main: Initialisation failed.")
    exit(1)
  assign(opt.x, init_x)
  assign(opt.Lambda, [0.]*n)
  assign(opt.xl, xl)
  assign(opt.xu, xu)
  while cnt.status < worhp.TERMINATE_SUCCESS and cnt.status > worhp.TERMINATE_ERROR:
    if worhp.get_user_action(cnt, worhp.Action.CALL_WORHP):
        #print("call worhp")
        worhp.worhp(opt, wsp, par, cnt)
    if worhp.get_user_action(cnt, worhp.Action.ITER_OUTPUT):
        #print("iter output")
        worhp.iteration_output(opt, wsp, par, cnt)
        worhp.done_user_action(cnt, worhp.Action.ITER_OUTPUT)
    if worhp.get_user_action(cnt, worhp.Action.EVAL_F):
        #print("eval f")
        user_f(opt, wsp, par, cnt)
        worhp.done_user_action(cnt, worhp.Action.EVAL_F)
    if worhp.get_user_action(cnt, worhp.Action.EVAL_DF):
        #print("eval df")
        user_df(opt, wsp, par, cnt)
        worhp.done_user_action(cnt, worhp.Action.EVAL_DF)
    if worhp.get_user_action(cnt, worhp.Action.EVAL_HM):
        #print("eval hm")
        user_hm(opt, wsp, par, cnt)
        worhp.done_user_action(cnt, worhp.Action.EVAL_HM)
    if worhp.get_user_action(cnt, worhp.Action.FIDIF):
        #print("fidif")
        worhp.fidif(opt, wsp, par, cnt)
        # No done_user_action!
  worhp.status_msg(opt, wsp, par, cnt)
  return opt.f, vectorize(opt.x)
```

Comment: Not easy to guess what is going on. See my answer for my best guess though. More information about the objective function and iteration output would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the Hessian is 0, WORHP will apply some regularisation to get positive definiteness which might slow down convergence. You could try setting the parameter `StartBettsTau` to a very small value like `1e-16` to avoid much of the regularisation.